# VirtualBox Guest Additions do not turn on shared clipboard and mouse

Tags: windows, virtualbox, debian, clipboard, guest-additions

I have Windows 7 host with several Debian 7.1 guests installed via VirtualBox 4.2.14.
I dont have X Window, or some other GUI addon on my Debian.
I have installed VirtualBoxGuestAdditions with option --nox11, but still got an error about installing X Window drivers. Neverthless people on the forums say that its ok and that parameter just prevents the installation from failing, but not prevents the error itself.
VirtualBoxGuestAdditions start when I load the guest machine: it is printed to the screen. The additions really work: I can use the shared folders.

Now I want to use

1. Shared clipboard
2. Mouse

Unfortunately, both of them do not work.

1. I try to copy in all the ways and directions: ctrl-c/ctrl-v, ctrl-u/ctrl-y, nano editor shortcuts, bash clipboard shortcuts, copying by mouse in Windows to paste in Debian and vice versa - no results. I wonder can I use Shared Clipboard without the GUI inreface in my Debian?
2. And the mouse is just captured as it was before by virtual machine. When its captured inside the machine window - I cannot see and use it.

Where I went wrong?
Or, may be, I just cannot use these features without installing X Window? If yes, can I istall X Window AFTER the additions installation?

UPDATE:
I have installed a very useful gpm utility which enables a mouse on my guest machine! Still I dont have a shared clipboard.